# net/http is not working with ipv6 address

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a "GET" request to a local ipv6 address (discovered via mdns). The issue is that the request [fails](https://play.golang.org/p/RMOi_B72fkq). Why is that?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://[fe80::cf5:b02f:27c3:2abe]:7070/kw/"
    rsp, err := http.Get(url)
    fmt.Println(rsp, err)
}
```

Output

```
<nil> Get http://[fe80::cf5:b02f:27c3:2abe]:7070/kw/: dial tcp [fe80::cf5:b02f:27c3:2abe]:7070: socket: Unknown protocol
```

Comment: care to say what's the down-vote for?

Comment: I would suggest that you have no IPv6 support on your system - but nothing is known about your system.

Comment: You also have a link local address with no scope. What exactly are you expecting to connect to?

Comment: @JimB I'm discovering some devices(a/v equipment) using zeroconfig and some of them have ipv6 addresses thus the reason I'm trying to connect to these ipv6 addresses

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect to an IPv6 link-local address, but these require a scope ID to be valid. The scope ID is usually the interface name or number (e.g. `enp4s0` or `wlp5s0` on Linux; `3` or `12` on Windows).

The `%` also needs to be escaped, because it appears in a URL. So it will appear as `%25`.

So your URL should appear as:

```
url := "http://[fe80::cf5:b02f:27c3:2abe%25interface]:7070/kw/"
```

Where `interface` is your scope ID.

---

Also note well that while `net/http` will happily make HTTP requests to IPv6 link-local address literals, web browsers will not. They will, however, connect to *names* which resolve to properly scoped link-local addresses. They will also connect to global (and ULA) IPv6 address literals. If you will eventually have a web browser involved in your project, keep this in mind.